# What is SAT most common meaning when speaking on study/school/students?

Tags: meaning, acronyms

What is SAT most common meaning when speaking on study/school/students (like at pages 27 and 31 - book "GRIT - author Angela Duckworth)")?

Comment: Are you talking about BrE, AE, or something else; and do you mean the acronym or the word *sat*?

Comment: Do you mean *Scholastic Aptitude Test*?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the excerpt from that book, since chances are most people are not gonna have that book on hand to reference those pages. Also, could you clarify what do you mean by study/school/students?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, in an academic context, SAT refers to a test that is used for college admissions in the US. Many Universities require SAT scores as part of an application. The SAT was first administered in 1926, and is stil administered as of October 2016. "SAT" originally stood for "Scholastic Aptitude Test", but has been changed several times, and currently the letters officialy do not stand for anything-it is a meaningless acronym.

http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/pages/frontline/shows/sats/where/timeline.html
https://magoosh.com/hs/sat/about-the-sat/2013/what-does-sat-stand-for/